# NullPointerException on unchanged bittorrent library of BitLet

Tags: java, bittorrent, torrent

I just put a torrent on it, did not change the code.

Console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.bitlet.wetorrent.Metafile.<init>(Metafile.java:87)
    at org.bitlet.wetorrent.Sample.main(Sample.java:35)
```

It's on this:

```
35: Metafile metafile = new Metafile(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));
```

In Metafile code:

```
87: byte[] announceByteString = ((ByteBuffer) rootDictionary.get(ByteBuffer.wrap("announce".getBytes()))).array();
```

I just got the source code to begin studing it, but it doesn't run.

---

Files:

- [Sample.java](https://github.com/bitletorg/bitlet/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bitlet/wetorrent/Sample.java)
- [Metafile.java](https://github.com/bitletorg/bitlet/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bitlet/wetorrent/Metafile.java)
- [Bencode.java](https://github.com/bitletorg/bitlet/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bitlet/wetorrent/bencode/Bencode.java) (a Metafile is a Bencode)

I changed just one line (from Sample.java):

From:

```
String filename = args[0];
```

To:

```
String filename = "C:\\Torrents\\Tao Of Jeet Kune Do By Bruce Lee (Pdf,Epub) Gooner.torrent";
```

It takes the torrent file name from the command line argument, I just put it on the code.

Comment: Looks like `filename` is null. Can you show how you instantiate it?

Comment: Please show the whole constructor of Metafile that is called and how you call it. (what filename is)

Comment: A quick look suggests that it's `rootDictionary` that is null here.

Comment: Scratch that, `rootDictionary` can't be `null`, it's `rootDictionary.get(...)` that returns `null`, so the exception is thrown when you try to call `.array()`.

Comment: And I have no clue. =/